# Convert date [2023-10-23T00:00](nvarchar) to date in format YYYY-MM-DD[2023-10-23]

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am struggling to convert a nvarchar field to date type. Whatever I try, it keeps coming back with the T00:00. Need some advice on this. I want to avoid substring or trim, is there a way to do it with a convert or cast?

Following is what I am trying

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEFIELD, 120) 
CAST (DATEFIELD as DATE)
```

Both are returning me with the T00:00 which I want to omit. Tried many of the examples on stackoverflow but nothing seems to work

Comment: I don't follow what you are asking. If your column `DATEFIELD` is an `nvarchar` then all `CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEFIELD, 120)` will do is change the data type; the style code is when you are converting from or to a string data type to/from a **non-string** data type; for string to/from string the style parameter is ignored.

Comment: `CAST (DATEFIELD as DATE)` can **never** return a value with `T00:00`, a `date` does *not* have a time portion. Your statement can only be false.

Comment: I want to convert the nvarchar to date and remove the T00:00. Should I be doing it a different way?

Comment: When I try a cast, I am getting an error 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

Comment: Infact, the second query you've provided, for the sample value in your title, errors: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9AUBqM9m)

Comment: Are all your times in the format `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm`?

Comment: **Date/DateTime values _always_ use a binary (non-readable) format!** If you need a specific format, you need a `varchar`... and you should **ONLY** do this when finally outputting data to show to the user. It's _extremely_ poor practice to allow datetime values to EVER store as varchar in columns.

Comment: yes, that is correct, unfortunately inherited this database, and the dates are in the format yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm

Comment: If you concatenate the seconds to the value (`:00`) then you won't get an error. SQL Server expects a (literal) date and time value to at least be accurate to 1 second.

Comment: @eddeveloper Then you need two steps: First, convert the old varchar value to a DateTime, to gain access to date formatting functions. Second, use the date formatting function to get back a varchar in the desired format.

Comment: substring the first 10 characters and cast it as a date?

Comment: used a combo of your suggestions and got it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> inherited this database, and the dates are in the format yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm

Assuming this really is a varchar column, then you need to do this in two steps:

1. Convert the varchar to a Date/DateTime to gain access to date functions
2. Use the convert or format function to get the desired output

   ```
   convert(varchar(10), cast(MyColumn + ':00' as datetime), 23)
   ```

Alternatively, assuming you already have **consistent** values that always have two-digit months and days, you can just take the first 10 characters:

```
substring(MyColumn, 1, 10)
```

But I suspect there's something else here. The language in the question is common with other questions I've answered where the author doesn't really understand what they have for the source or destination data type.

Answer (score 0):

```
CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONCAT(DATEFIELD, ':00'), 121) AS DATE)
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**

Comment: If the format really matters, this actually results in a **binary** value that leaves you up to the whims of whatever client system you're using to show any format it wants, and it just happens that yyyy-MM-dd is a common (not universal!) default. Often this binary value is actually desirable, but again: _if the format actually matters_ you should think in terms of creating a pre-formatted varchar result instead of a binary Date.

Answer (score -1):

If you want particular format, like 'YYYY-MM-DD', use `format` function:

```
FORMAT(DATEFIELD,'yyyy-MM-dd')
```

Comment: `FORMAT` does nothing to an `(n)varchar` value.

Comment: Just wrap `DATEFIELD` in `cast(... as date)`

Comment: Which we're already proven [causes an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77053189/convert-date-2023-10-23t0000nvarchar-to-date-in-format-yyyy-mm-dd2023-10-2/77053404?noredirect=1#comment135836068_77053189) with the OP's data...